# What kind of data structure should I use to implement UPGMA?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, c++14, c++17

I am going to apologize in advanced since I do not know how to ask this question or my title would be better.

I am trying to implement the [UPGMA Algorithm from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA). Say I have a vector of vector of ints.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> test = { {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}}
```

Where the integers represent a particular string that is in my program. Now, let's say I have specific input telling me to merge `test[0]` and `test[3]` together, once they are merged, we push back the merged vectors to the end, and we delete `test[0]` and `test[3]` which would look like this:

```
test = { {1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {0,3} }
```

This is easily achieved by the following piece of code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 3;
merge = {test[x][0],test[y][0]}; // merge is a std::vector<int>
test.push_back(merge);
test.erase(test.begin() + x)
test.erase(test.begin() + y - 1); // -1 since the first erase shifts everything over
```

The problem happens when I want to merge `test[1]` and `test[4]`. The desired result would look something like this:

```
test = { {1}, {4}, {5}, {2,{0,3} };
```

This is where I run into my problem, because it seems I have now introduced a `std::vector<std:vector<int>>` into position 3 of my test. And using `merge = {test[x][0],test[y][0]}` will fail. This will get worse as time goes on. Since I could have something that potentially looks like this:

```
test = { {1}, {{4,5},{2,{0,3}}} }
```

I think I am quickly realizing that I have the wrong data structure for this, but I have absolutely no idea on what data structure I need to use for this. What kind of data structure can I use to easily implement this?

Again, I apologize for the bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a binary tree. Each child is either an `int` or a sub-tree. This is not usefully modelled in a `vector` of anything.

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using Node = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<class Tree>, int>;

struct Tree {
    Tree(Node left, Node right) : left(left), right(right) {}
    Node left;
    Node right;
};

std::pair<std::vector<Node>::iterator, std::vector<Node>::iterator> decide_merge(const std::vector<Node> & v)
{
    // Some process to choose elements
    return { v.begin(), v.begin() + 1 };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodes = { {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5} };
    while (nodes.size() > 1)
    {
        auto [left, right] = decide_merge(nodes);
        auto tree = std::make_shared<Tree>(*left, *right);
        nodes.erase(left);
        nodes.erase(right);
        nodes.push_back(tree);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just checking this out, but this doesn't compile? I have run it with the c++17 flag but there is an undefined reference to decide_merge.

Comment: Yes. You don't describe the mechanism to choose what nodes to merge.

Comment: it is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA) on the wiki. Essentially, you create a matrix based on the distance which I have already calculated. The smallest number other than 0, is chosen, and those are merged together.

Answer (score 1):

You're building a tree here. It's probably best to do so by creating new nodes here. So when you merge {0} and {3}, you create a new node which has the value {0,3}. And if you then merge {2}, you create a node {2,0,3}.

At this point you might object and say that you need the structure {2,{0,3}}. That's actually not needed, and in fact is inefficient. You only need the structure at the end of the process. At that point, you can reconstruct the tree from the fact that you haven't actually erased old nodes - you just set them aside.

This basically means you need a second vector of vectors. After you've created {0,3}, you move {0} and {3} to that second vector. After you have created {2,0,3}, you append {2} and {0,3} to that second vector.

This isn't the most memory-efficient implementation of course. The second vector has size O(N*N) as it keeps every intermediate tree node. A more space-efficient implementation would be to replace the second vector of vectors with an simple tree, where the leaf nodes have just a single value and the non-leaf nodes have only two child pointers. This tree just keeps the structure.

Comment: I guess I have a hard time trying to figure out how to create a matrix out of each of those differences. The algorithm is straight forward, and I have the matrix of the initial differences. However, I am not sure on how to even implement on what you are suggesting. Would that not require knowing the vector {0,3} exists somehow?

Comment: @Sailanarmo: Of course it exists. After iteration 1, {0,3}  is in the first vector; after iteration 2 it's moved to the second vector because now the first vector contains {2,0,3}